# Raspberry Pi Zero seems dead

Tags: pi-zero

I have a problem with a NEW Raspberry Pi Zero 1.3 being recognised through USB port. 
With the SD card inserted, it boots fine, but it doesn't recognise the keyboard or mouse through the USB-OTG adapter.
Connecting directly to a Windows PC ( micro-USB to USB cable , no SD card ) it is not recognized as "BCM2708 Boot". Is this a broken micro-USB port sign or a configuration issue ?

Comment: You need to elaborate, and read https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Testing with a Raspberry Pi Zero W it is recognized by Windows as BCM2708 Boot without inserted SD card

Comment: As you guessed... You probably have a defective board.  You may want to rework your question to indicate your prior testing of working boards.

Comment: Cool so you confirmed your OTG port data lines work (with the SD card out), and I assume 'boots fine' implied you had a display for that case with the SD card in. Have you ruled out power limitations problems via an externally powered hub? See my answer to [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/67094/dell-usb-keyboard-not-working-with-my-pi-zero) regarding how this is a common issue with the Pi Zero. Once tested, please clarify by editing your post accordingly!